# While running playwright script getting error "Error: No tests found"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, playwright

I have created one folder with xyz name but running script through terminal getting error "Error: No tests found" but if same script I have take out from the folder test runs successfully

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjt6E.png)

Comment: In playwright.config, make sure that the `testDir` option points to the admin folder.